# Extracting values of nested objects in JSON

Tags: json

Updated question, with full code in relevant places:

```
var app=express()

app.get('/api/imagesearch/:topic',function(req,res){
    var topic=req.params.topic
    var offset=req.query.offset

    var opts = {
        host: 'www.googleapis.com',
        path: '/myapi'  
        // The result of calling this URL below
        };

    https.get(opts,function(resp){
          resp.pipe(bl(function(err,data){
          if(err) throw err
          // data is a buffer
          var myString=data.toString() // string
          var myData=JSON.parse(data.toString()) // object
          var myArray=myData.items // array

          var result=[]
          myArray.forEach(function(element){
            result.push({"url":element.pagemap.cse_image[0].src,
                         "snippet":element.snippet,
                     "thumbnail":element.pagemap.cse_thumbnail[0].src,
                        "context":element.link})

          })

              res.end(JSON.stringify(result))

    }))

  })
```

})

Result of calling the URL https://www.googleapis.com/myapi

```
var myData={"items":[
   {
      "snippet": "string",
      "link": "string",
      "pagemap": {
               "cse_image":[{
                             "src":"value" }],

               "cse_thumbnail":[{
                             "src":"value"}]

              }

    },
    {
      "snippet": "string",
      "link": "string",
      "pagemap": {
               "cse_image":[{
                             "src":"value" }],

               "cse_thumbnail":[{
                             "src":"value"}]

              }

    },...]}
```

The request is:

```
https://www.myweb.com/api/imagesearch/cat?offset=1
```

The point is that the call of the first key in myArray.forEach (element.snippet,element.link,element.pagemap) return correctly the desired array. **The problem when calling the nested keys: element.pagemap.cse_image, element.pagemap.cse_thumbnail return TypeError:cannot read property  'cse_image' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `JSON.parse()`. `myData` is already a JSON object and not a String.

`Array.each()` is not a standard JS function. Use `forEach()` instead. Are you using a library?

**UPDATE:** I've created the following [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8uugdmr/) for you. Check the console for the output.

Comment: Sorry, I am using forEach not each. Not, I am no using a library. I see that myData is a object, but if don't use JSON.parse(myDate) when trying of iterate `myData.items` gives a error in forEach: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please try out the code snippet.

Comment: That is exactly what I did but it gives a error indicating that the forEach is a property of **undefined** Might be I could indicate some code precedent to that. The beginning is a response of a http.request in node. The callback function gives data as a buffer that I converted to string through the toString() method. So the **data** as buffer ==>  **data.toString()** as string ===> **JSON.parse(data.toString())** as JSON object

Comment: Can you update your question with example code and request. Seems like the buffer is empty.

Comment: I updated the question. Not, the buffer is no empty as the first property _element.pagemap_ returns correct output. The problem is with the nested properties _element.pagemap.cse_image_, _element.pagemap.cse_thumbnail_. Probably I have been missing some step.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: cannot read property `cse_image` of `undefined`. That means that `pagemap` is missing in at least one of the objects returned from the server. Is this an optional property? If yes, check if it's undefined.

Comment: I think I found the solution. When calling the URL https://www.googleapis.com/myapi it is displayed only 10 items of the query, but it seems the buffer is filled with all the items of the query and sometimes the value of pagemap property is missing. So when iterating through the array and finding some of this missing values, it returns error no property of undefined. Only is needed a check of the values of pagemap:`if(typeof element.pagemap=="object"){return element.pagemap.cse_image}`